# How to implement SSL/HTTPS on local JSP website?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, ssl, https

I have a JSP web app running in Netbeans locally on my Macbook for a school project. Part of the project is to setup HTTPS. Thus far in my life, anytime I added HTTPS to my server it was as simple as buying an SSL certificate and asking my webhost to install it for me so I've never actually seen how the installation works.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether Tomcat is installed as the sole webserver, or if you have a primary webserver that is passing requests to Tomcat.

If you have either IIS or Apache HTTPD installed and have connected them to Tomcat via JK/Tomcat connector, install the SSL certificate in IIS or Apache HTTPD following the instructions for installing SSL cerificates in those webservers that can be found all over the web.

If you are using Tomcat by itself, follow the instructions here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Note that the use of JK is not necessary if you are fronting Tomcat with another web server. You can use a plain-old HTTP proxy as well (e.g. mod_proxy_http in Apache httpd).